# How to avoid that the top of a label is sliced off

Tags: labeled

In this simple example, the top of the capital letter on the Y-Axis is sliced off. How can that be avoided?

```
Labeled[Plot[-x^2 - 4, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 500, AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}], {"Top of T Sliced Off", "X-Axis"}, {Left, Top}, RotateLabel -> True]
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Win 10, Mma 12. Everything is perfectly visible.

Comment: I am using 11.1.1.0

Comment: try `Pane["Top of T Sliced Off"]` instead of  `"Top of T Sliced Off"`?

Comment: In this case instead of `Labeled` I would use the option `Frame->True`, or `PlotTheme->"Scientific"`. That should work in v.11.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch, can I ask you to demonstrate?

Comment: @user120911 Please have a look at the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This repeats your image with the option `Frame->True`:

```
    Plot[-x^2 - 4, {x, 0, 5}, ImageSize -> 500, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["Top of T Sliced Off", 16, Black], 
    None}, {None, Style["X-Axis", 16, Black]}}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Black, White}, {White, Black}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, Range[5]}}]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Instead of "painting" with `FrameStyle` you also can turn on/off sides: `Frame -> {{True, False}, {False, True}}`.